# What would a world be like where gravitational force on protons was equal to electromagnetic force

Tags: gravity

Imagine a world where the gravitational constant was much stronger such that the electromagnetic force on two protons was roughly the same as the gravitational force.

In such a world quantum gravitational effects couldn't be ignored.

Also black holes would form much more easily.(?)

And gravitons would be detectable (or would they?)

What in general would the Universe be like. Would it be filled with black holes or normal matter? Would there be neturon atoms held together by gravity? What else?

Comment: The Planck mass would be ~ 10 GeV and the Planck length only 2 orders of magnitude shorter than a fermi. Atomic physics would not be qualitatively altered, but nuclear and particle physics would, and hence those features [most] of atomic physics predicated on nuclear structure.

Comment: We don't have any theory that would include gravity at a quantum level in a manner that's good enough to make these sort of predictions.  Without a complete theory for quantum gravity I don't see how your question could be answered.

Comment: @StephenG well some things would be known and some wouldn't

Answer (score 2):

While the quantum effects would be hard to predict without a good quantum gravity theory, it is easier on the macroscopic scale. The difference in strength between electromagnetism and gravity to a large degree sets the size scale hierarchy of the universe. A force of gravity $10^{36}$ times larger will make most everyday objects implode.

[Following (Adams 2016):](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06958.pdf) The stellar mass scale is set by the gravitational fine structure constant as $$M_{star}\approx \alpha_G^{-3/2} m_p = (\hbar c/G)^{3/2} m_p^{-2} \approx 1.85 M_\odot$$ Were $\alpha_G\approx 1/137$ rather than $5.91\times 10^{-39}$ we would get stars of mass $7.3\times 10^{-55}M_\odot \approx 874 m_p$. That is, if you did not have fusion reactions to keep them apart when you bring together a few hundred atoms, they would be above the Chandrasekhar mass and tend to implode. The luminosity scales with the fourth power of $G$ - in this universe fusion would happen nearly instantly even in small clumps of matter, the energy release would be huge, and then the remnants would implode gravitationally when they cool.

Planets have sizes defined by being supported by electromagnetic forces against gravity. If they are equal then planets cannot remain stable. [The number of atoms in the planet has to be below a limit scaling as](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06958.pdf) $\alpha_G^{-3/2}$ - planets cannot contain several atoms.